# T-SQL convert string to date

Tags: sql

I have a long string (column type nvarchar) which contains a date; I am extracting this date and copy the string in a new table. This string has this format:

```
Mon, 3 Dec 2012 11:53:07 +0000
```

I want to convert this as a date:

```
select convert(datetime,'Mon, 3 Dec 2012 11:53:07 +0000',101) from table
```

but i get this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

Comment: Try dropping the "+0000" part of the string and see if that works for you... that'll be fine if all your dates are in UTC.

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx; 127 is the only format supporting timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of brute-force to account for the non-standard date/time string format, but it works, provided you don't need to capture timezone data...

```
DECLARE @datestring VARCHAR(50) = 'Mon, 3 Dec 2012 11:53:07 +0000'

SELECT
    CAST(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@datestring,6,20)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle that string in it's entirety the solution's not straightforward as none of the standard formats match.  Instead you need to rip out a few bits and play about with it to match a standard format, then manipulate it as required:

```
declare @d nvarchar(128) = 'Mon, 3 Dec 2012 11:53:07 +0000'
, @dt datetime
, @hh int
, @mm int
select @dt = SUBSTRING(@d,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@d),charindex('+',@d)-1-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@d))
, @hh = cast(SUBSTRING(@d, LEN(@d)-5,1) + SUBSTRING(@d, LEN(@d)-4,2) as int) 
, @mm = cast(SUBSTRING(@d, LEN(@d)-5,1) + SUBSTRING(@d, LEN(@d)-2,2) as int)
select dateadd(minute,@mm,dateadd(hour,@hh,convert(datetime,@dt,113)))
```